# Getting below error while connecting to PySpark session

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

Overwriting default python with Anaconda3 python..This is on AWS Linux2 and can able to set Python and pip alias as below. tried exporting pyspark as below but it is not reflected. How can I fix this ...

```
###Set PySpark
sudo tee -a /etc/skel/.bashrc <<"EOF"
export PYSPARK_PYTHON="/apps/softwares/anaconda3/bin/python"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="/apps/softwares/anaconda3/bin/python"
EOF
source ~/.bashrc


   $ which python
    alias python='/apps/softwares/anaconda3/bin/python'
            /apps/softwares/anaconda3/bin/python

$ which pip
alias pip='/apps/softwares/anaconda3/bin/pip'
        /apps/softwares/anaconda3/bin/pip

$ which pyspark
/usr/bin/pyspark

$ python
Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 16:21:59)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

$ pyspark
Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 16:21:59)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pyspark import SparkConf
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from pyspark.context import SparkContext
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pyspark import accumulators
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/accumulators.py", line 97, in <module>
    from pyspark.serializers import read_int, PickleSerializer
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 72, in <module>
    from pyspark import cloudpickle
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 145, in <module>
    _cell_set_template_code = _make_cell_set_template_code()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 126, in _make_cell_set_template_code return types.CodeType(
TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)
>>>
```